# Better way to use a variable in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to have a template which would be used to create dynamic user detail forms. But I need to have different `ids` for all elements, so as to post the details correctly. My template looks like:-

```
<div id="user-template" class="hidden">
    <div class='lbl-div' id='user(user_number)'>
        <label>User(user_number)</label>
    </div>
    <label class="lbl" id="user(user_number)_firstname">Firstname:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" />
    <label class="lbl" id="user(user_number)_lastname">Lastname:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" />
</div>
```

Here, `user_number` is a variable. `onclick` of a button would pick this template-->replace user_number with a global variable-->increment the global variable-->append the modified template as a child to the parent `div`.

I replace the variables as:-

```
template = template.replace(/\(user_number\)/g, count);
count++;
```

Here `count` is the global variable.

Is there a better way to achieve this(using the `template` dynamically with changing ids)?

Comment: Do you need those `id` values for anything else?

Comment: you can just use `name` attribute for all inputs, and refer to the one you want with `$("#formid").find("input[name='<name>']")`

Comment: yes, that will be required to retrieve the values from post request.

Comment: @BarunSharma: `id`s aren't sent with form submissions. `name`s are.

Comment: I am even ok for a dynamically changing `name`. Any thing to uniquely identify the elements.

Comment: Ordinarily I would just replace whatever the `InnerHTML` is after retrieving the specific DOM element. I would keep track of the variable using a variable in JavaScript. I assume you have considered this?

Comment: @doveyg ....Yes I have done that. I am new to working on HTML and JS. Just wanted to check, is this way of replacing the variable in template ok?

Comment: If it works its ok. You will find many more ways to improve your code overtime the more and more you write, Its a natural progression.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using html templates, then try using any templating engine, like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/). But templating engine will not give you two way binding between template and your data. It just render template with given data.

If you want to use pure two way databinding application, then try using web application frameworks like [angularjs](https://angularjs.org/) or [emberjs](http://emberjs.com/).

Comment: Thanks for this. But I am not looking for making any major changes as of now. Just checking how it can be done in the conventional way?